# Python datatable/pandas reshaping problem

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, reshape, py-datatable

I need to reshape my df.

This is my input df:

```
import pandas as pd
import datatable as dt

DF_in = dt.Frame(name=['name1', 'name1', 'name1', 'name1', 'name2', 'name2', 'name2', 'name2'],
             date=['2021-01-01', '2021-01-02', '2021-01-03', '2021-01-04', '2021-01-05', '2021-01-06', '2021-01-07', '2021-01-08'],
             type=['a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a'],
             value=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])

   | name   date        type  value
-- + -----  ----------  ----  -----
 0 | name1  2021-01-01  a         1
 1 | name1  2021-01-02  b         2
 2 | name1  2021-01-03  a         3
 3 | name1  2021-01-04  b         4
 4 | name2  2021-01-05  b         5
 5 | name2  2021-01-06  a         6
 6 | name2  2021-01-07  b         7
 7 | name2  2021-01-08  a         8
```

This is the desired output df:

```
DF_out = dt.Frame(name=['name1', 'name1', 'name2', 'name2'],
              date_a=['2021-01-01', '2021-01-03', '2021-01-06', '2021-01-08'],
              date_b=['2021-01-02', '2021-01-04', '2021-01-07', None],
              value_a=[1, 3, 6, 8],
              value_b=[2, 4, 7, None])

   | name   date_a      date_b      value_a  value_b
-- + -----  ----------  ----------  -------  -------
 0 | name1  2021-01-01  2021-01-02        1        2
 1 | name1  2021-01-03  2021-01-04        3        4
 2 | name2  2021-01-06  2021-01-07        6        7
 3 | name2  2021-01-08  NA                8       NA
```

If necessary the datatable Frames can be converted into a pandas DataFrame:

```
DF_in = DF_in.to_pandas()
```

Transformation:

- This is a grouped transformation. The grouping column is 'name'.
- The df is already sorted
- The number of rows in each group is different and can be even or uneven
- If the first row in a group has a 'b' in the column 'type' it has to be removed (example: row 4 in DF_in)
- It is also possible that the last row in a group has an 'a' in the column 'type', this row should not get lost (example: row 7 in DF_in)

I hope this explanation is understandable.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Given that `name1` is the value for `name` in both of the first two rows, why is `2021-01-04` matched to `2021-01-03` instead of to `2021-01-01` for date and `4` to `3` instead of to `1` for value? Is this just by proximity?

Comment: Exactly it is by proximity. The df is sorted and a row that contains the value 'a' in the column 'type' should be matched to the row below it if it contains the value 'b'. This has to happen groupwise. It gets a bit more difficult since the number of rows per group is not always even and they don't always start with the value 'a' and end with the value 'b' in column 'type'.

Comment: @k_n_c do you have any idea for this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you all very much for your answers. In the meantime I developed a solution that uses only datatable package a uses some workarounds for the current limitations:

1. define a function to create id for adjacent rows: 1,1,2,2,...
2. create column id that contains row index
3. get id of rows to be deleted as list
4. subtract row id's to be deleted from all row id's
5. subset the Frame based on the remaining row id's
6. get number of rows per group
7. use the function for each group and use the number of rows as input,
   create a list with all results (same length as Frame after subset). Bind this to the Frame
8. create two subset Frames based on column type ('a' or 'b')
9. join df2 on df1

code:

```
import math
import datatable as dt
from datatable import dt, f, by, update, join

DF_in = dt.Frame(name=['name1', 'name1', 'name1', 'name1', 'name2', 'name2', 'name2', 'name2'],
                 date=['2021-01-01', '2021-01-02', '2021-01-03', '2021-01-04', '2021-01-05', '2021-01-06', '2021-01-07', '2021-01-08'],
                 type=['a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a'],
                 value=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])



def group_id(n):
    l = [x for x in range(0, math.floor(n / 2))]
    l = sorted(l * 2)
    if n % 2 != 0:
        try:
            l.append(l[-1] + 1)
        except IndexError:
            l.append(0)
    return l


DF_in['id'] = range(DF_in.nrows)
first_row = f.id==dt.min(f.id)
row_eq_b = dt.first(f.type)=="b"
remove_rows = first_row & row_eq_b
DF_in[:, update(remove_rows = ~remove_rows), 'name']
DF_in = DF_in[f[-1]==1, :-1]
group_count = DF_in[:, {"Count": dt.count()}, by('name')][:, 'Count'].to_list()[0]
group_id_column = []

for x in group_count:
    group_id_column = group_id_column + group_id(x)

DF_in['group_id'] = dt.Frame(group_id_column)
df1 = DF_in[f.type == 'a', ['name', 'date', 'value', 'group_id']]
df2 = DF_in[f.type == 'b', ['name', 'date', 'value', 'group_id']]

df2.key = ['name', 'group_id']
DF_out = df1[:, :, join(df2)]
DF_out.names = {'date': 'date_a', 'value': 'value_a', 'date.0': 'date_b', 'value.0': 'value_b'}

DF_out[:, ['name', 'date_a', 'date_b', 'value_a', 'value_b']]

   | name   date_a      date_b      value_a  value_b
-- + -----  ----------  ----------  -------  -------
 0 | name1  2021-01-01  2021-01-02        1        2
 1 | name1  2021-01-03  2021-01-04        3        4
 2 | name2  2021-01-06  2021-01-07        6        7
 3 | name2  2021-01-08  NA                8       NA
```

Comment: @sammywemmy, thank you very much for cleaning up the solution - it needs only 30% of the time to run compared to the original code.

Comment: You are welcome @peter. Hopefully more functions are added to datatable to remove these limitations

Answer (score 1):

Let us work with dataframes, so load the data first

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(name=['name1', 'name1', 'name1', 'name1', 'name2', 'name2', 'name2', 'name2'],
             date=['2021-01-01', '2021-01-02', '2021-01-03', '2021-01-04', '2021-01-05', '2021-01-06', '2021-01-07', '2021-01-08'],
             type=['a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a'],
             value=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]))
```

Then in the below we do the following steps

- get rid of second `b`s
- assign the group number in column 'g'
- pivot the table via `set_index` + `unstack`
- rename the columns to the desired format
- drop unneeded columns

```
df1 = df[~((df['type'] == 'b') & (df['type'].shift() == 'b'))].copy()
df1['g'] = np.arange(len(df1))//2
df2 = df1.set_index(['g','type']).unstack(level=1)
df2.columns = ['_'.join(tup).rstrip('_') for tup in df2.columns.values]
df2.drop(columns = 'name_b').rename(columns = {'name_a':'name'})
```

output

```
    name    date_a      date_b      value_a value_b
g                   
0   name1   2021-01-01  2021-01-02  1.0     2.0
1   name1   2021-01-03  2021-01-04  3.0     4.0
2   name2   2021-01-06  2021-01-07  6.0     7.0
3   name2   2021-01-08  NaN         8.0     NaN
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. The first step of your solution is not robust for my data however. The last row of a group might contain an 'a' and the first row of the next group might contain a 'b'. Getting rid of secondary 'b' would fail in this case.

Comment: Also, the second line of your code should be performed per group since the number of rows in a group can be uneven.

Answer (score 1):

datatable does not have reshaping functions that allow flipping between vertical and horizontal positions; as such, pandas is your best bet.

Below is my attempt at your challenge:

```
    from datatable import dt
    import pandas as pd

    df = DF_in.to_pandas()

    (df
     .assign(temp = df.index, # needed for ranking
             b_first = lambda df: df.groupby('name')['type'].transform('first'))
     .assign(temp = lambda df: df.groupby('name')['temp'].rank())
      # get rid of rows in groups where b is first
     .query('~(temp==1 and b_first=="b")')
      # needed to get unique values in index when pivoting
     .assign(temp = lambda df: df.groupby(['name','type']).cumcount())
     .pivot(['name','temp'], ['type'], ['date','value'])
     .pipe(lambda df: df.set_axis(df.columns.to_flat_index(), axis='columns')
     .rename(columns = lambda df: "_".join(df)))
     .droplevel('temp')
     .reset_index()
      )

    name      date_a      date_b value_a value_b
0  name1  2021-01-01  2021-01-02       1       2
1  name1  2021-01-03  2021-01-04       3       4
2  name2  2021-01-06  2021-01-07       6       7
3  name2  2021-01-08         NaN       8     NaN
```

Summary:

- Filter out the rows where 'b' is the first entry in the group
- to avoid error due to duplicate indices when pivoting(reindexing), create a temporary cumcount column
- the rest relies on pivot and some name editing (set_axis and rename functions). You can abstract a bit further with the [pivot_wider](https://pyjanitor.readthedocs.io/reference/janitor.functions/janitor.pivot_wider.html) function from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor.readthedocs.io/index.html):

  ```
   # pip install pyjanitor
   import janitor

   (df
   .assign(temp = df.index, 
           b_first = lambda df: df.groupby('name')['type'].transform('first'))
   .assign(temp = lambda df: df.groupby('name')['temp'].rank())
   .query('~(temp==1 and b_first=="b")')
   .assign(temp = lambda df: df.groupby(['name','type']).cumcount())
   .pivot_wider(index=['name', 'temp'], 
                names_from=['type'], 
                values_from=['date','value'],   
                names_sep="_",
                names_from_position='last')
   .drop(columns='temp')
    )
  ```

Comment: Hi @sammywemmy, thanks for your answer. I will check it out. Also I came up with a solution without converting to pandas. I am curious what you think.