# How to create a sparse rating matrix from a dataframe for a recommender system?

Tags: python, sparse-matrix, collaborative-filtering, recommendation-engine

I have a pandas dataframe with nearly 90 million rows that contain user_id and item_id which corresponds to each user and their interacted item. I want to build a collaborative filtering model with implicit feedback. However, since the size of my dataset is large, I could not handle it. I'm not using a big data infrastructure like Spark or Hadoop. How can I create a sparse rating matrix from the dataframe using Python?

Comment: In what way do imagine the size of the dataframe to be reduced?

Comment: Just to provide one way, not sure it is possible or not?  Use the `datatable` package in python and refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66932526/python-datatable-pandas-reshaping-problem). Hope it helps.